# Changing the favicon in the JBPM web client

Tags: jboss, redhat, jbpm, business-process-management

I started learning jBPM for my upcoming project. Just curios to know if the icon (favicon.ico/png) of the web client can be changed.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am serious. I see the tool is in Apache License. Trying to change the branding...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe you can replace drools.gif from the business-central.war/images directory with whatever image you want to replace.